# Strange error when I use \AA

Tags: beamer, siunitx, units

I want to use \AA in my PhD presentation to insert Angstrom units and I am using the siunitx package. But when I compile my tex I get the error

> LaTeX Error: Command \AA unavailable in encoding T1.

I am using a template for beamer in my Overleaf profile. How can I solve the problem?

The problem should not be in the package versions, because I have an other document in Overleaf that has not the same problem. The other document is a beamer presentation and it uses the siunitx package.

My suspect is that the problem is inside the .sty file, I am using the UiB theme. Inside the .sty file there is a line

```
\RequirePackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
```

and I have the suspect that I need to insert an other "kind" of alphabet to take the /AA symbol.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: If you are using the `siunitx` package anyway, try `\si{\angstrom}` or `\SI{1}{\angstrom}`.

Comment: It should work just fine. As Mico asks, (1) which latex installation are you using (it say at the top of the  log file). (2) Can you provide a full minimal example that others can try.

Answer (score 5):

The macro `\AA` is a text-mode macro. For use with the `\si` and `\SI` macros of the `siunitx` package, you should write, say, `\si{\angstrom}` or `\SI{1}{\angstrom}`.

An MWE (minimal working example and its output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Anders Jonas \AA ngström, 1814--1874.

\si{\angstrom}, $\SI{1}{\angstrom}=\SI{e-10}{\meter}$.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the same error if I use for instance  $r_{FA}=$\SI{2}{\angstrom} . I do not understand why.

Comment: @TheOldJonny - Please tell us which TeX distribution you employ and when it was last updated. Similarly, which version of the `siunitx` package do you employ? (This information may be found in the log file.)

Comment: @TheOldJonny - Do you get a different result if you replace `$r_{FA}=$\SI{2}{\angstrom}` with `$r_{FA}=\SI{2}{\angstrom}$? Just curious.

Comment: Yes, I obtain the same errors

Comment: @TheOldJonny - To repeat my earlier questions: Which TeX distribution to you employ, when was it last updated, and which versions of `beamer` and `siunitx` are installed on your system? FWIW, I use MacTeX2021, updated less than a week ago; LaTeX2e `<2020-10-01> patch level 4`, beamer `2021/02/09 v3.61`, and siunitx `2020/02/25 v2.8b`. (All version information may be found in the log file.)

Comment: it is not a problem of version, because in Overleaf I have two beamer presentations: in one \AA works, in the other one not,

Comment: @TheOldJonny: depending on time of creation of the files, your two files on Overleaf may be using different LaTeX versions. You can check this yourself by clicking the Overleaf button to the top left of the screen when your file is loaded, it will show the TeXLive version used for that file.

Comment: @TheOldJonny - You claim, "it is not a problem of version". Unless you actually provide some specific answers to the questions we've asked, there's no way of ascertaining what's going on.

Comment: @Mico the OP is using a beamer theme that uses `gfsneohellenic` and it does not define `\AA` in T1 encoding.

Comment: @daleif - Wow, that's phantastic sleuthing!! +1.

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the issue

From the OPs code (sent by private email) we can make the following MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\let\textlozenge\relax
\usepackage[default]{gfsneohellenic}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pbk}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Helvetica
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr} % Courier
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  $\SI{200}{\angstrom}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

where the font choice comes from a provided beamer theme.

When I compile the example on my TeXLive 2020 setup I get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \AA unavailable in encoding T1.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

We can boil it down even further as

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\let\textlozenge\relax
\usepackage[default]{gfsneohellenic}
\begin{document}
\AA
\end{document}
```

gives the same error. But replacing `\AA` by `Å` does work, so the char is there.

Looking in `gfsneohellenic.sty` we do find

```
\DeclareTextSymbol{\AA}{OT1}{197}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\aa}{OT1}{229}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\AE}{OT1}{198}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\ae}{OT1}{230}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\O}{OT1}{216}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\o}{OT1}{248}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\OE}{OT1}{140}     
\DeclareTextSymbol{\oe}{OT1}{156}
```

but they are not defined for T1 encoding, hence the error.

Just adding `\DeclareTextSymbol{\AA}{T1}{197}` to the preamble after loading `gfsneohellenic` does seem to work.

Since that package has not been updated since 2001, it might be an idea to contact the authors. (see also the `\textlozenge` hack needed to even load the package)

Comment: First of all, thank you. I have sent an email to the author of the template, but I have not recieved any email. I will search for the package authors to signal the problem